# NSMutableArray losing data

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I have create a property for `NSMutableArray` and when Assign a value to it I have written a following code

```
[self setTotalCells:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"data"]]];
```

I am using it in searchbar method. however once I used that property then the array is becoming empty.

```
cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSLog(@"filterContentForSearchText");
NSLog(@"**************************************************************");
if ([totalCells count]<= 0) {
    totalCells = [_jsonPropertiesDictionary valueForKey:@"data"];
}
NSLog(@"%@",totalCells);
NSLog(@"**************************************************************");
for (id cell in totalCells)
{
    NSLog(@"bedrooms : %@",[cell valueForKey:@"BEDROOMS"]);
    NSLog(@"DISPLAY_ADDRESS : %@",[cell valueForKey:@"DISPLAY_ADDRESS"]);
    NSLog(@"PRICE : %@",[cell valueForKey:@"PRICE"]);
    NSLog(@"searchText : %@",searchText);
    NSComparisonResult result = NSOrderedAscending;
    if ([[cell valueForKey:@"BEDROOMS"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [[cell valueForKey:@"BEDROOMS"] length] > 0) {
        result = [[cell valueForKey:@"BEDROOMS"] compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
            [self.filteredListContent addObject:cell];
    }
    if ([[cell valueForKey:@"DISPLAY_ADDRESS"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [cell valueForKey:@"DISPLAY_ADDRESS"] != nil && [cell valueForKey:@"DISPLAY_ADDRESS"] != @"" && [[cell valueForKey:@"DISPLAY_ADDRESS"] length] > 0) {
        result = [[cell valueForKey:@"DISPLAY_ADDRESS"] compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
            [self.filteredListContent addObject:cell];
    }
    if ([[cell valueForKey:@"PRICE"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [cell valueForKey:@"PRICE"] != nil && [[cell valueForKey:@"PRICE"] length] > 0) {
        result = [[cell valueForKey:@"PRICE"] compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
            [self.filteredListContent addObject:cell];
    }
    if ([searchText isEqualToString:@"" ]) {
        filteredListContent = totalCells;
        break;
    }
}
if (self.filteredListContent.count > 0) {
    cells = self.filteredListContent;//added by prajakta
}

[self.propertyList_table reloadData];
NSLog(@"filteredListContent : %@ ",filteredListContent);
```

I have declared this property as

```
@property(atomic,retain)NSMutableArray *totalCells;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: ...and what is your problem?

Comment: the problem is after one iteration i am not getting any value in totalcells

Comment: your searching method are very interesting, why don't you try to filter the `NSArray` using the `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method? it won't mess your original datasource at all. beside, your code fragment does not give us too much information. where does it run anyway?

Comment: my search method has only that code. what do you want to know? so that accordingly i will edit my question.

Comment: i would suggest you to use self.totalCells while accessing the values

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use to filter this way? it won't ruin you original data source...

```
cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSLog(@"filterContentForSearchText");
NSLog(@"**************************************************************");
if ([totalCells count]<= 0) {
    totalCells = [_jsonPropertiesDictionary valueForKey:@"data"];
}
NSLog(@"%@",totalCells);
NSLog(@"**************************************************************");

/*
 * replace your code FROM here...
 */

NSArray *filteredCells = [totalCells filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSDictionary *cell = (NSDictionary *)evaluatedObject;
    if ([[cell valueForKey:@"BEDROOMS"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [[cell valueForKey:@"BEDROOMS"] length] > 0) {
        return [[cell valueForKey:@"BEDROOMS"] compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
    }
    if ([[cell valueForKey:@"DISPLAY_ADDRESS"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [cell valueForKey:@"DISPLAY_ADDRESS"] != nil && [cell valueForKey:@"DISPLAY_ADDRESS"] != @"" && [[cell valueForKey:@"DISPLAY_ADDRESS"] length] > 0) {
        return [[cell valueForKey:@"DISPLAY_ADDRESS"] compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
    }
    if ([[cell valueForKey:@"PRICE"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [cell valueForKey:@"PRICE"] != nil && [[cell valueForKey:@"PRICE"] length] > 0) {
        return [[cell valueForKey:@"PRICE"] compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
    }
    return FALSE;
}]];

/*
 * TO here...
 */

if (self.filteredListContent.count > 0) {
    cells = self.filteredListContent;//added by prajakta
}

[self.propertyList_table reloadData];
NSLog(@"filteredListContent : %@ ",filteredListContent);
```

Comment: Thanks Holex. I will definitely try this.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure how and where you lost the content of the original `NSArray`, your provided code fragment does not seem to critical but it may have some if you really lose the data...